# Copying data from one database table to another table on different servers

Tags: java, mysql, sql, database

I have a database table that has 109 columns.I need to copy the rows with all the columns from the table to another which is on a different server.To achieve this i have to use java.My idea is using a class instance to store the rows in an arraylist.But this is highly inefficient.Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

You can use dump the data from one table in a file and then restore it to other database. If you are using MySQL and Java then use `SELECT * FROM test INTO OUTFILE 'filepath'` to create a dump and use `LOAD DATA INFILE 'filepath' INTO TABLE test`. You will need to create an empty table at the destination first.

Answer (score 0):

109 column is quite high. I hope writing a program to "write records to new DB as its copied from old DB would be better". So drop the idea of storing it'll take much overhead. You can use some mapping framework like Hibernate and achieve this with a POJO class.

BTW you can get the migration done instead of this! why Java? was I missing something.

Comment: Because it will be a web service,the data transfer is not one time,it will be periodic,with updates after the first insert.So definately i need to use java which is the basis of my application.

Comment: so what you are trying to achieve is a replication. then you can try my suggestion. Two hibernate connections. get the data from server A into a Pojo class A, transfer those to Pojo Class B which is mapped with Server B (via annotation or xml mapping). While the Connection to Server A is still ON, commit new record to Server B and repeat the process till last row is reached.

Comment: You can also try simple POJO JDBC sometime Hibernate if not configured correctly will get you into trouble.